# Using a model with a generic List and store in SQLite 3

Tags: c#, sqlite, maui, or-mapper

I wanted to use a `List<MyItem>` in my Model within my .NET MAUI App and store it in my SQLite 3 database.

When I use the following model and try to insert it with `InsertAsync(…)` I get an Error that the Table does not exist.

```
[Table("MyItemStorageTable")]
public class MyItemStorage
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]     // Primary Key already indexed in Table
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Unique]                        // Primary Key combined with ID
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Brand { get; set;}
    
    public List<MyItem> MyItemList { get; set; }

}
```

Well, okay it wants to store these List-Items in a separate table.

What is your recommendation to do this? I don’t want to do a lot of manual stuff to keep these two tables in sync and have a lot of Code in the background that does this stuff.

Was expecting that the OR Mapper can handle it on it’s own?

What is the preferred way to handle this?

========== Edit: following models and no entry for List ==========

Sorry, but it did not work in my .NET-MAUI App. I installed the following NuGet [SQLite.Net.Extensions.Async](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/) (3.0.1) and changed my models as follows:

```
[Table("MyItemStorageTable")]
public class MyItemStorage
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]     // Primary Key already indexed in Table
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Unique]                        // Primary Key combined with ID
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Brand { get; set;}
    
    [OneToMany]    // One MyItemStorage can have many MyItem
    public List<MyItem> MyItemList { get; set; }

}
```

```
[Table("MyItemTable")]
public class MyItem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]     // Primary Key already indexed in Table
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Unique]                        // Primary Key combined with ID
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```
//[Table("MyItemStorageMyItems")]
public class MyItemStorageMyItems
{
    //[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    //public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(MyItemStorage))]
    public int MyItemStorageId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(MyItem))]
    public int MyItemId { get; set; }
}
```

**Init() of my DatabaseService**

```
static async Task Init()
{
    if (Database is not null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);

    await Database.CreateTableAsync<MyItemStorageMyItems>();
    await Database.CreateTableAsync<MyItemStorage>();
    await Database.CreateTableAsync<MyItem>();
}

public static async Task AddMyItemStorage(MyItemStorage myItemStorage)
{
    await Init();

    await Database.InsertAsync(myItemStorage);
}
```

First of all, when I drop all tables and start from scratch, I get an exception that the Table **MyItemStorage does not exist** which is strange as the InsertAsync(...) should create it. When I restart my App it does not generate this error anymore.

Unfortunately, the Table **MyItemStorageMyItems** does not show any values, but **MyItemStorage** shows entries. So still, there is no List stored.

What am I doing wrong here? And before asking, I checked in the DatabaseService.AddMyItemStorage(...)-Method, the list items are all available.

Comment: you need to use SQLite Extensions for FK relations

Comment: Do I have to manage my relations and create Tables on my own then, or is this done in background and I can use something like a ```List<MyItem>```?

Comment: please read the [docs](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/)

Comment: I added my code to my question. Unfortunately, without success. My List<MyItem> is not stored

Comment: Read the docs again.  I believe you need to use the “WithChildren” methods

Comment: I am sorry, obviously it was late for me and I did not recognize my problem :(
What I still struggle with is the Error "SQLite.SQLiteException: 'no such table: MyItemStorage'" when I save items the first time. Then it crashes - when I relaunch my App and save again I can do it without having issues.